# Best pattern for functions that apply to a preexisting class hierarchy

Tags: c#, c++, design-patterns, language-agnostic, hierarchical-data

I have an existing class hierarchy, *that I can not modify*

ie a phylogenetic tree:

```
base
├── animal
│   ├── invertebrate
│   └── vertebrate
│       ├── amphibian
│       ├── bird
│       ├── fish
│       ├── mammal
│       └── reptile
└── plant
```

I need to build a library of functions for objects in that hierarchy, ie print functions:

```
print_mammal_A()
print_mammal_B()
print_fish_A()
print_vertebrate_A()
print_vertebrate_B()
print_animal_A()
```

- These functions will be developed as they're needed.
- There may be more than one function for each class.

The obvious solution is to make a class hierarchy of wrappers that maps the target hierarchy. Each wrapper implementing it's own function, ie:

```
class base_wrapper(){
  base * base_ptr;
}

class animal_wrapper : base_wrapper{
  void print_animal_A();
}

class vertebrate_wrapper : animal_wrapper {
  void print_vertebrate_A();
  void print_vertebrate_B();
}
```

I'd like to know of design patterns that allow either of the following items:

- Removing wrapper inheritance (so the library developer doesn't need to know of the target class bases)
- Automatically wrap with the most specialised wrapper for the target class (so the library user doesn't need to know of the target class bases)

I'm interested in either, C# or C++ solutions. Not sure if there are patterns that can be implemented easily in one and not the other.

Comment: I'm interested in either, C# or C++ solutions. Not sure if there are patterns that can be implemented easily in one and not the other.

Comment: I am assuming you cannot modify the library it self so you cannot add functions directly to each class?

If I am understanding this correctly I think you could use extension methods.  In C# it would be something like this.

`public static class FishExtension`
`{`
`public static void Print(this Fish fish)`        {
          // Now you can work with the fish object.
        }
    }   
}

The user of fish will then be able to do:

'Fish fish = new Fish();'
'fish.Print();'

Comment: Does the library developer need to know about the existence of the existing class hierarchy?

Comment: Sorry I also wrote this as an answer since the comment layout is so bad.

Comment: Yes, I can't modify the hierarchy library, no, the neither the library developer nor user need to know of the hierarchy, but the user needs to have all the hierarchical functions available.

Comment: There is no additional hierarchy, you stick with the old hierarchy but are simply adding methods to already created classes.

Comment: The second answer has for @dbugger. Your solution works for me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you cannot modify the library it self so you cannot add methods  to each class?

If I am understanding this correctly I think you could use extension methods.  In C# it would be something like this.

```
public static class FishExtension
{
    public static void Print(this Fish fish)
    {
     // Now you can work with the fish object.
    }
}
```

The user of fish will then be able to do:

```
Fish fish = new Fish();
fish.Print();
```

This way there is no additional hierarchy (no wrappers)
The extension class in never used directly, the user only has to import its namespace.

See the Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bb383977.aspx